# Massive import/create ApplicationUser from file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I need to import data from file and create Identity User

I open a stream and I read each line async. In each loop I do _userManager.CreateUser(user, password). Everything work fine, but there is a problem: about 1 minute to create 1000 user. Now, there is a method to create 100.000 users  (using always identity, stores, hasher, ecc...) without waiting 2 hours?

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath ?? throw new Exception("Wrong file path")))
{
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
         var line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
         var newUser = new User();
         var password = "Foo_123!";
         [...]                    
         await _userManager.CreateAsync(newUser, password);
    }
}
```

I expected a faster method or a way to save changes at the end of file.

Thank you

Comment: Are the 100k users in the same file?

Comment: What is the information did you read from file? Based on your code, it's not sure what you used. Share us the full code you used from read file to `await _userManager.CreateAsync(newUser, password);`.

Comment: It is just to understand that there is an iteration. If it's easier for you: `for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++){ var user = 'User'+i; var password= 'Foo_123!'; await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);` Is not possible await 2 hours to import users